# Slow Azure worker role response times

Tags: c#, azure

I have a created a simple "Hello World" service using OWIN and Nancy running in an Azure Worker Role. When running locally, I get response times of ~1ms. Once I deploy it, it takes around 250~400ms. It is running on a single Standard_A1 instance. I do not think that this is a Nancy issue as I get similar response times when using WebApi instead of Nancy. I know that it isn't the network I am accessing it from as the monitors are also showing similar response times.

[image]

Here is my publish profile:

[image]

My WorkerRole.cs class is below:

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private readonly ManualResetEvent runCompleteEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private IDisposable _app = null;

    public override void Run()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("StackOverflow.Example is running");

        try
        {
            this.RunAsync(this.cancellationTokenSource.Token).Wait();
        }
        finally
        {
            this.runCompleteEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 64;

        var endpoint = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["DefaultEndpoint"];
        string baseUri = String.Format("{0}://{1}", endpoint.Protocol, endpoint.IPEndpoint);

        Trace.TraceInformation(String.Format("Starting OWIN at {0}", baseUri), "Information");

        _app = WebApp.Start<Startup>(new StartOptions(url: baseUri));

        bool result = base.OnStart();

        Trace.TraceInformation("StackOverflow.Example has been started");

        return result;
    }

    public override void OnStop()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("StackOverflow.Example is stopping");

        this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        this.runCompleteEvent.WaitOne();

        if (_app != null)
        {
            _app.Dispose();
        }

        base.OnStop();

        Trace.TraceInformation("StackOverflow.Example has stopped");
    }

    private async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // TODO: Replace the following with your own logic.
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("Working");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

My app.config is as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="owin:HandleAllRequests" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here is the controller:

```
public class MonitorController : NancyModule
{
    public MonitorController()
        : base("/api")
    {
        Get["/monitor"] = x => "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what could be causing it or how I could even being going about trying to figure the cause?

Comment: Erm. Might this have something to do with it? `await Task.Delay(1000);`

Comment: @RichTurner That actually made the response take 3x longer... That part is actually generated from the VS Template.

Comment: Sorry, so I understand, if you take out the delay, the responses take 3x times longer? Should take LESS time if you take out the delay.

Comment: I actually don't think so. RunAsync is in reality just a glorified while loop to keep the Role running continuously. Without it, all I am going to see is a stream of Traces being written. I would get the same effect if I did I while(true) statement in the Run method. That is how I used to see it in examples.

Comment: Yep - read more thoroughly ;) Where are you geographically relative to the west coast of the US?

Comment: San Diego. When I run the request in Fiddler, the biggest gap is between ServerGotRequest and ServerBeginResponse.

Comment: Interesting. Deployed my own version of your service (practically identical code) to http://bitcrazed-test.cloudapp.net:10100/. Avg response time over 5 refreshses is ~47ms - 90ms (I am in Seattle. Svc in Azure West).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the endpoint through the VIP vs. the *cloudapp.net url fixed this.